# isEqualToString: not comparing strings correctly

Tags: ios, nsstring, compare

I have two strings that are exactly the same, but they are not being compared as equal. One string is a mutable string, and the other is a normal string, and I have a if statement that checks if the two strings are equal. The output for the two strings is this:

```
2013-04-08 09:09:31.555 Pin2Own[650:1303] 6447 E Crocus Dr
2013-04-08 09:09:31.555 Pin2Own[650:1303] 6447 E Crocus Dr
```

The top is a mutable string, and the bottom is the normal string. I have tried converting the mutable string to a normal string, but I am having the same problem. I am getting the mutable string from a xml document in a NSXMLParser subclass, and the other from a mutable array in a singleton. Here is the code for the NSXMLParser class:

```
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    address = nil;
    zpid = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"street"])
    address = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"zpid"])
    zpid = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if(address)
    [address setString:string];

    else if(zpid)
    [zpid setString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"street"])
    NSLog(@"%@", address);

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"zpid"])
    NSLog(@"zip id is: %@", zpid);
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{    
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[Data singleton] annotations];

    for (MapPoint *mp in annotations)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", mp.fullAddress);
        if ([mp.fullAddress isEqualToString:address])
        {
            mp.zpid = zpid;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Did not match address");
        }
    }
}
```

SO I am comparing the two addresses, and setting a property if the addresses are the same, which I have made sure will always be true. Does anyone see if there is something wrong? I really have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Have you checked the length of the two strings to see if they're the same? There may be whitespace or other unprintable characters.

Comment: There is probably some hidden characters if it's been copy and pasted from somewhere

Comment: Ok I found that the mutable string is 49 characters, and the normal string is 16 characters. Is there a way to make the mutable string 16 characters?

Comment: Ok I found what is happening. I am screwing up the parser, so by the time the parsers reaches the end of the document, the mutable string has changed to the last element of the xml document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try trimming the whitespace characters from your strings before comparing them. You can use the following

```
firstString = [firstString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
secondString = [secondString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
BOOL stringsAreEqual = [firstString isEqualToString:secondString];
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't blame on trusted `isEqualToString:` method.

You must have some spaces added in leading or trailing of any address string.

Use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning strings is an art more than a science, but in the case of whitespace it can be done fairly well:

```
// Various types of whitespace in the input string
NSString *dirtyStr = @"   \tJoe\t Doe \n 42,    Main St. \n\rMetropolis    12345  ";

// First trim the initial and final white space characters away
NSString *trimmed  = [dirtyStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSLog(@"Trimmed: \"%@\"", trimmed);

// Then remove repeated space characters in the middle (if consistent with your requirements)
NSString *cleaned  = [trimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s+" withString:@" " options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, trimmed.length)];

NSLog(@"Cleaned: \"%@\"", cleaned);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your string contain invisible control characters?

```
string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""]
```